# "Всех тридцать задержанных"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, количественно-именное-сочетание, одушевленность

"Напомним, ранее всех тридцать задержанных обвинили в пиратстве"
(Из новостей)

Как это сказать по-русски?
"всех тридцати задержанных" - это уже родительный падеж получается, а тут требуется явно винительный... Но ведь так тоже не годится? Или я придираюсь?

//-----------
Дополнение.

gecube тут намекал на известную грамматическую неопределенность объекта-субъекта.
Но это решается легко, субъект ставится перед сказуемым, объект - после:
***"Власти обвинили тридцать задержанных"***
Никаких вопросов не вызывает.
Но для сочетания "все тридцать задержанных" невозможно подобрать самое падеж. 
***"Власти обвинили (все) тридцать задержанных"***

Во жеж  где собака порылась...

//-----------
Еще одно дополнение.
Был в полной уверенности, что тут **нет** правильной формы (кроме вариантов изменения структуры фразы) и мне быстро объяснят, почему именно. Увы. Я подожду результатов еще двух ресурсов, на Лингве пока еще разборки в самом разгаре.

//-----------
В полемику с гражданином Дерзким и его мультами не вступаю не потому, что мне нечего ответить, а исключительно по причине беспардонного удаления им своих аргументов. Все разумное, доброе и вечное при таком подходе виснет в воздухе и для непосвященного превращается в малявы резидентов Кащенки.

//-----------
27.09.2014

Я давно забыл об этом вопросе, но ответ Сержа заставил меня вспомнить.

Я совершенно не согласен с тем, как Грамма его поняла.
В её ответе много рассуждений о винительном падеже - и совсем нет ключевого слова - "одушевленность".

Речь не о том, в каком падеже сочетание ставить, а каким будет этот (винительный) падеж.

Продублирую с учетом того, что разговор год назад явно зашел в тупик.

*Вижу все столы. [Сколько видишь столов?] -Вижу все. Вижу тридцать столов. Вижу все тридцать столов*. Вопросов нет, все варианты соответствуют винительному неодушевленному.

*Вижу всех слонов. [Сколько видишь слонов?] -Вижу всех. Вижу тридцать слонов. Вижу все**(???)** тридцать слонов*.

Почему в этом случае "все" ставится - По мнению Граммы, хотя бы - в форму Винительного неодушевленного? Ничего ведь к этому не располагает, кроме необходимости как-то "привязать"  (согласовать?) к последующему числительному. 
Или все-таки нужен винительный одушевленный? Или, может, здесь вообще несовместимость согласования и, как следствие, лакуна в грамматике?

(+)

Если бы было позволено признать, что имя числительное само по себе, вне сочетаний,  обладает или может обладать категорией одушевленности, вопрос бы решился мгновенно. Необходимость согласование по одушевленности требовало бы нужной формы все/всех. Но это слишком радикальное предложение по пересмотру современной модели грамматики. Боюсь даже предлагать.

Comment: Не знаю,  но мне слух не режет.

Comment: >Мне слух не режет  
  
О как! Именно в таком согласовании? (Или оно тут управление?)
Придется посчитаться с Вашим мнением - и привлекать дополнительных экспертов... Ибо Вы пока в меньшинстве.

Comment: Не знаю почему. Может, в сочетании с числительными как-то изменяется одушевленность- неодушевленность?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Много чего перечитала, пока искала, почему я не  слышу ошибку, хотя понимаю, что может быть и по-другому.

Answer (score 11):

Из русской Грамматики.

"Числительные непоследовательно обозначают одушевленность или неодушевленность тех существительных, с которыми они сочетаются. **Из количественных числительных на одушевленность указывают только слова два, три и четыре**: видел две (три) картины, но двух товарищей, трех подруг; поднял четыре кубика, но поднял четырех котят.

На одушевленность существительных, с которыми они сочетаются, указывают все собирательные числительные, например: дежурил трое суток, видел четверо саней, но видел обоих студентов, троих солдат, четверых отдыхающих."

Получается, что правильно употребить собирательное числительное. Но тридцатеро... Все-таки они только до десятеро существуют. Проверяла через словари он-лайн. Десятеро - находит, одиннадцатеро - выдает, что нет такого слова, а тридцатеро исправляет на тридцать евро))). Так что если нет такого слова, приходится признать вариант в вопросе правильным.

---

Добавляю. Вот что нашла. 
Собирательные числительные

Собирательные числительные — это замкнутая группа слов: двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро; в разговорной речи образуются и числительные типа одиннадцатеро, двенадцатеро **(но не *двадцатеро,* тридцатеро).** Собирательные числительные называют количество, понимаемое как нечто целостное, единое.

Современный русский литературный язык / Под ред. П. А. Леканта — М., 2009г.

И еще у **Голуб** в **"Стилистике русского языка"** :
"Категория одушевленности проявляется **только** при употреблении числительных два, три, четыре при указании на живые существа".
[Голуб](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook028/01/part-022.htm)

**Таким образом, В.п. - обвинили всех тридцать задержанных**.  Категория одушевленности в сочетаниях с числительными не проявляется(кроме числительных два, три, четыре). Это значит, что форма, как у неодушевленных, отвечающих на вопрос  Что? Если хотим подчеркнуть одушевленность, то используем собирательное числительное (обвинили семерых, восьмерых, девятерых, десятерых задержанных). Т.к. слова тридцатеро нет, то остается только вариант в.п. тридцать задержанных.

Comment: >>И все равно останется вопрос о степени ненормативности словосочетания "обвинили тридцать задержанных"     
  
Здесь-то какие вопросы???  Без "всех", которое-то и требует после себя собирательной формы (для одушевленных имен), никаких сложностей не вижу.

Comment: >В состав собирательных числительных традиционно включают следующие числительные *оба, двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро*. Реже упоминается ещё десять (реже одинадцать) «потенциальных», редко употребительных лексем (*одиннадцатеро – двадцатеро и тридцатеро*).

Микаэлян И. Л., Зализняк Анна А. "Вместе или раздельно"

Редкость употребления слова не означает, что его не существует.

Comment: Согласна, убрала. Это я до всех своих изменений писала.

Comment: Там говорится не о редкости, а о потенциальности. Потому что составных собирательных вообще и представить невозможно. О нормативности же вообще ничего. У Леканта же специально подчеркивается ненормативность слов двадцатеро и тридцатеро. И в словарях, повторюсь, их нет.

Comment: Вот еще с портала русского языка Астраханского гоударственного университета:"Собирательные числительные – это слова, обозначающие определённое количество предметов или лиц как совокупность.
Состав собирательных числительных ограничен 10 лексемами: двое, трое, четверо, пятеро, шестеро, семеро, восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро, оба (обе), причём лексемы восьмеро, девятеро, десятеро употребляются крайне редко." 
Думаю, достаточно.

Comment: >Редкость употребления слова не означает...
  
Она означает, что нормативность сомнительна. Не хочу более уходить от темы. Вопрос не в правильности слова "тридцатеро", а в винительном падеже для сочетания "все тридцать человек (задержанных)".
И. все тридцать человек/задержанных  
Р. всех тридцати человек/задержанных  
Д. всем тридцати человекам/задержанным   
В-???  
Т. всеми тридцатью человеками/задержанными     
П. о всех тридцати человеках/задержанных

Comment: А скажите-ка мне - "все/всех" - это числительное таки или местоимение? Или вообще неведома зверушка?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. )))
Местоименное числительное это. Тут я согласен с Кузнецовым.
Самое смешное, что Лопатин этого слова не знает.

Comment: Добавила последний абзац в ответ.

Comment: Угу. Ясно. Спасибо. Хотя и не ожидал такого мнения...

Answer (score 3):

1. новости пишут те еще грамотеи. Видел очень много описок и неправильных управлений.
2. Еще часто бывает неясно что есть субъект, а что объект. "Microsoft купил Skype" - кто кого купил????
3. Правильно: "Напомним, ранее все тридцать задержанных были обвинены в пиратстве" (пассив) или "Напомним, ранее всех тридцати задержанных обвинили в пиратстве" (актив)

Comment: ~1. да, но не по теме.
~2. см. 1.
~3. Это я и сам знаю. Как сказать, не перестраивая фразу. 

Если нельзя, то почему?

Comment: @behemothus, касательно перестроения фразы - ок, но иногда приходится и так выкручиваться. Почему нельзя - я ж предложил вариант, который звучит по-русски. Чем не нравится? Тут по-моему заказывака, что мы считаем главным словом. Обвинили (кого? что?) задержанных (каких?) всех. Ну, или обвинили (скольких/кого?) тридцать (кого? чего?) задержанных. Вероятно, в зависимости от этого плавает смысл - упор на то СКОЛЬКО было задержанных или КОГО именно обвинили.

Comment: Или вопрос в том как надо писать тридцать/тридцати/тридцатерых? Ну, так и сформулируйте сам вопрос тогда конкретно, пожалуйста!

Comment: gecube, выкрутиться - не проблема. Я умею это делать. В данном случае - чисто спортивный (академический) интерес.

Answer (score 3):

По-русски будет один из вариантов:

1. *Все тридцать задержанных были обвинены в пиратстве.*
2. *Всех задержанных, в количестве тридцати человек, обвинили в пиратстве.*
3. *Всех тридцатерых задержаных обвинили в пиратстве.*

Comment: Вот насчет третьего варианта 
Остальное - это уже неспортивно. ;) Ибо фразу перестаивает.
Вопрос в допустимости формы "тридцатерых".

Comment: Собирательные числительные бывают только двое - десятеро.

Comment: У Гоголя в "Тарасе Бульбе":

> Били двадцатерых, побьём и пятнадцать.

Мне слух полные десятки в форме собирательного числительного слух не режут.

"Всех" просит после себя собирательности (уберите его или "30" и фраза вполне благозвучная), поэтому или "тридцатерых", или изменять фразу, поэтому и три варианта.

Comment: @Ларf, у Валгиной ([ССЫЛКА](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-085.htm)) После "десятеро" идёт "и т.п.", что предполагает наличие и других собирательных числительных.

Comment: Спасибо. Я где-то читала, что только до десятеро, тоже в каком-то учебнике, не вспомню сейчас точно.

Comment: Хорошо бы где-нибудь увидеть написанным (а где, как не  в словаре искать слово?). Просто  и т.п.  - недостаточно. Гоголь -  тоже не аргумент.

Comment: >Всех тридцатерых задержаных обвинили в пиратстве.

+1

*По моему скромному мнению*, народ на чисто разговорном уровне, без всяких правил и даже несмотря на правила, не любит склонять **большие числительные**. Приблизительно так всё что больше десяти. Больше двадцати -- так наверняка.

**"Десятерых задержаных обвинили..."** говорится, на мой взгляд, вполне легко.

Обычный человек постарается избежать фразы вроде *"командир с 58 бойцами"*. Проще привести большое число к именительному падежу. *"Командир и пятьдесят восемь бойцов"*.

Comment: В этом, на мой взгляд, и есть причина того, что фраза в вопросе НЕ ЗВУЧИТ.

Кого? Всех задержанных. Склоняется легко. 

А вот с числительным "тридцать" сложнее. Не принято, не любят, у нас на разговорном уровне такое склонять. Десятерых, четверых -- пожалуйста, легко.

Comment: Не в этом дело. Тридцать - тридцати - не великий труд просклонять.

Answer (score 2):

Числительные два, три, четыре и собирательные числительные могут выражать категорию одушевленности-неодушевленности при сочетании с существительными.
Числительное тридцать не выражает эту категорию, следовательно, В.п. будет совпадать с И.п.  А может ли выражать одушевленность/неодушевленность  стоящее перед счетным оборотом определение?
  В «Грамматике-80»  сходные  ситуации не рассматриваются, поэтому попробуем определить выбор падежа на слух,  для чего возьмем следующие исходные данные:
   а)  два числительных: ТРИ – выражает категорию одушевленности/неодушевленности, ТРИДЦАТЬ – не выражает эту категорию,
   б) Наличие определений:  нет определения – определение относится к существительному – определение относится к счетному обороту.

На стажировку уехали (И.п.):
три студента, три лучших студента, первые три студента,
тридцать студентов, тридцать лучших студентов, первые тридцать студентов.

Мы встречали (В.п.):
трех студентов, трех лучших студентов, первых трех студентов,
Тридцать студентов, тридцать лучших студентов, ПЕРВЫХ ТРИДЦАТЬ СТУДЕНТОВ.

Если верно «первых тридцать студентов», то делаем вывод: во-первых, определение перед счетным оборотом не согласуется с существительным; во-вторых, определение перед счетным оборотом может проявлять определенную самостоятельность и выражать категорию одушевленности/неодушевленности, даже если числительное его выразить не может.
В результате останавливаемся на варианте  «Власти обвинили всех тридцать задержанных».

Порядковое числительное "первый" и местоименное прилагательное "весь" сходны по грамматическим показателям - скорее всего, они  ведут себя одинаково по отношению к счетному обороту.

Мысль 1. Вижу всех троих бегунов"  - мне кажется, что значение собирательности здесь излишнее, так как слово «всех» уже выражает собирательность (в полном составе, без изъятия). Поэтому лучше сказать: «вижу всех трех бегунов». Скорее всего,  в данной теме мы можем вообще обойтись без собирательности, тем более что «собирательность» далеко не каждому дана.

Мысль 2. Вряд ли слово «тридцатеро» пропишется в нашей речи, и дело здесь не в разрешении или запрещении  – он просто неудобно для произношения.

Мысль 3. Мы должны «на слух» различать Р.п. и В.п. (смысл всегда важнее сочетаемости грамматических значений).
Победа всех тридцати бегунов -  звучит прекрасно, никто не сомневается, что это Р.п.
Вижу  ВСЕ тридцать бегунов, вижу  ВСЕХ тридцать бегунов  (В..п.)  - хотя оба варианта с изъянами  (мне больше нравится второй, так как в нем слово ВСЕХ обозначает одушевленность), тем не менее смысл их ясен, так как числительное «тридцать»  в обоих случаях подсказывает нам, что это   В.п. 
Вижу  всех тридцати бегунов (В.п.)   - это звучит совсем странно, так как  слушатель уверен, что перед ним Р.п.

Мысль 4. Подобные конструкции лучше вообще не применять и заменять их другими, например:Всем тридцати задержанным властями предъявлены обвинения. Мы же не говорим, например, 22 сутки.

Comment: >Если верно «первых тридцать студентов»  
  
Не факт. Но даже если так, то непонятно, как из формы порядкового числительного "первых" вытекает форма для местоимения "все".

Comment: В вопросе Вы спрашиваете про числительное 30. А ответ теперь хотите услышать про числительное 31, 32 и на этом основании называете предыдущие ответы неубедительными... Где логика?

Comment: Нет. Хочу услышать все еще про тридцать. Про 31 - постольку, поскольку это может прояснить картину.    
Вот рассуждаю я про числительные разные - чтобы понять, как вообще сказывается категория одушевленности на числительных. Одушевленность проверяю по винительному падежу. Если сочетания "31 баран", "32 барана" и т.д. одушевлены, то логично предположить, что и "30 баранов" одушевлено, нет? Если сама идея такого обобщения некорректна, прошу сформулировать, почему.    
Неубедительными я назвал только аналогии, причем не все, а построенные по принципу "у Ивана два сына, значит и у Петра тоже".

Answer (score 0):

***Вот ответ справочной службы русского языка( Грамма.ру).***

Глагол ОБВИНИЛИ управляет винительным падежом зависимого слова (кого? что?), а значит, словосочетание ТРИДЦАТЬ ЗАДЕРЖАННЫХ дано в нужной форме.
Здесь примем во внимание то, что это словосочетание объединяет числительное ТРИДЦАТЬ и существительное (а точнее, субстантивированное причастие) ЗАДЕРЖАННЫХ, то есть в форме винительного падежа, как и в форме именительного падежа, в нем «главенствует числительное  -  управляет существительным (последнее стоит в форме родительного падежа множественного числа).
В цитируемом предложении это словосочетание дополнено местоимением  ВСЕ. В конструкции ВСЕ ТРИДЦАТЬ ЗАДЕРЖАННЫХ ничего необычного нет, хотя и можно задать вопрос: логично ли подчеркивать с помощью слова «всех точно названное количество человек  -  ведь оборот "всех задержанных" вполне информативен. Впрочем, о контексте и тексте, в котором употреблено это высказывание, нам ничего не известно, поэтому этот вопрос оставим в стороне. Обратимся к грамматическим особенностям конструкции ВСЕ ТРИДЦАТЬ ЗАДЕРЖАННЫХ. В косвенных падежах местоимение должно принимать форму, которую требует управляющее слово. Следовательно, в обсуждаемом предложении местоимение должно быть согласовано с числительным ТРИДЦАТЬ, а в итоге фрагмент должен иметь вид ВСЕ ТРИДЦАТЬ ЗАДЕРЖАННЫХ ОБВИНИЛИ.
Понятно, что в этом случае глагол из безличного легко превращается в личный, и предложение приобретает совсем иной смысл. Ставя местоимение в форму ВСЕХ, автор высказывания стремится уйти от иного смысла, но при этом игнорирует нормативные грамматические связи слов в конструкции с числительным.

***Дополнение (от Граммы.ру***)

Глагол ОБВИНИЛИ требует винительного падежа зависимого слова, а значит, ответ на Ваш вопрос о том, может ли в этом высказывании числительное ТРИДЦАТЬ быть употреблено в форме родительного падежа, является отрицательным.
У числительного ТРИДЦАТЬ форма винительного падежа омонимична форме именительного падежа (то есть слово "совпадает" при описании морфологической специфики этих форм не отражает ее сути в полной мере). Омонимия форм объясняется исторически: числительное ТРИДЦАТЬ первоначально употреблялось как существительное и сохранило особенности склонения существительного.

Comment: @behemothus, отвечала Грамма.ру, я в скобках написал. См.выше. Ссылкой поделиться не могу, ее нет. Они отвечают в личных сообщениях  почте. Я привел их ответ полностью.
Двусмысленность все же есть; она заключается в местоимении все. Т.е. если использовать местоимение все, вместо всех, придает иной смысл. Т.е. обвинили не задержанных, а задержанные обвинили.

Comment: Серж, Я считаю правильной форму "всех тридцать задержанных". На эту тему есть интересная статья http://www.ruslang.ru/doc/melchuk_festschrift2012/Mikaelian.pdf

Вот выдержки из нее: Числительное, само оставаясь вне категории одушевленности, «как бы проводит через себя одушевленность» от существительного к внешнему (стоящему слева от числительного) модификатору: Я вижу всех 〈этих, моих〉  десять мальчиков.

Comment: Но если для малых числительных согласование по одушевленности внешних модификаторов кажется обязательным, то для числительного "сто" налицо ВАРИАТИВНОСТЬ: Главная задача — обучить и организовать этих 100 человек. Но: Задача для организаторов с виду достаточно проста — это найти помещение на месяц и собрать эти 100 человек, которые хотят начать свой бизнес с нуля.

Comment: behemothus, вот мой вопрос. Недавно на одном форуме русского языке возник спор. Автор приводит такое предложение: "Напомним, ранее всех тридцать
 задержанных обвинили в пиратстве " (Из новостей). вопрос в том, корректно ли
 здесь употреблено числительное тридцать? Ведь после определения    "всех "
 числительное употреблено в вин.пад. , а смыслу нужен род.пад. В
 грамматике-80,
 ничего об этом не говорится. Так, корректно ли здесь употреблено
 числительное
 тридцать или же все-таки нужен родительный падеж? Конечно можно перестроить
 предложение на пассив, но интересует именно это предложение.

Comment: София,да,с вами согласен. Но как быть, например, с таким предложением: Он подошел к тридцати заключенным ? Или здесь иной случай?

Comment: Но в Д.п. числительное согласуется с существительным (или  субстантивированным словом). И проблем с определениями в косвенных падежах нет, например: Он обратился к этим тридцати заключенным.

Comment: >behemothus, вот мой вопрос  
  
Ясно, спасибо. При такой формулировке вопроса никаких претензий к ответу Граммы не имею. Шире вопрос - шире и ответ.